# Aptana saving css does not auto refresh the "show preview editor"

Tags: css, refresh, aptana, live, preview

Hello i just used Aptana Studio 3.0 3 days ako and im liking that its free and its previewing my html/php code by just saving. Although this is not just a very huge problem, I would like the "Show Preview Editor" tab to refresh in saving the css code like saving the html/php codes.

I have my css inside a folder of my default web folder (mywebsite/css/style.css)

tldr:

I would like a way for the "Show Preview Editor" page to passively refresh on CSS save not by actively clicking the refresh button.